# Zonal statistics tool excluding some features in ArcMap?

Tags: raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

In Arcmap 10.6, while using Zonal Statistics as Table tool, some of my feature zone data is being excluded from my output table.

Here is the scenario. I'm using a polygon layer of buildings, with a raster layer above it that represents radio coverage.  Each pixel is an integer value representing signal strength at that area.  My intention is to add attributes to the building polygons that represent the amount of signal power in their are. I'm using **Zonal Statistics to Table** tool to with buildings as my **feature zone data** and FID as the **Zone field**.  I'm using radio coverage raster as my **Input Value raster**.  The output is a table that includes a row for each polygon/building, ( except those that are inexplicably missing  ), and each row has a value for based on the raster signal strength values in that polygon's area.  As an example, the polygon in light blue is one of the polygon/buildings being left out.  It's well within raster coverage as can be seen by the **Pixel Inspector** tool.  Also the pixels are smaller that the building, 10' x 10'. The surrounding features are being included.  Out of 48400 polygon/buildings, about 80 seemingly randomly located building are being excluded from the output.

Can someone please tell me why?

Also as a side note. I originally had this problem using 1100' x 1100' pixels.  I read somewhere that the pixels should be smaller than the polygons.

Why is that?

If a single pixel covers several polygons, shouldn't all the polygons inherit the value of the pixel that's completely covering it?

[image]

Comment: Repair geometry http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003v000000 on your buildings and see if that helps. Are any of your intended buildings overlapping? If so this will cause problems as the zone data is rasterized by the tool, the rasterized version can only have the ID of one building.

Comment: Yes.  You can see that the purple polygons are buildings.  In this case its the blue highlighted rectangle in the middle of a larger purple building.  It represents a courtyard in a larger building.  The other similar courtyards aren't excluded though.  Also the tool returns a table, not a raster.

Comment: During the execution of the tool the polygons are converted to a raster *If the zone input is a feature dataset, a vector-to-raster conversion will be internally applied to it.* from http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000 ; if you have overlapping buildings you're going to have problems and will need to planarize your polygons or write some python to get the result you're after.

Comment: Similar quetion: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261429/some-zones-disappear-when-running-zonal-statistics-as-table-in-arcgis/261457#261457