# Zonal Statistics is returning null values in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, null

I am using Zonal Statistics as Table to obtain the Max height from a DEM for each polygon (then Joined to the polygons).  For some reason, a lot of the polygons get NULL returned.  All the polygons returning Null appear to be between 1 - 4 cells in size (given the DEM scale).  Other same sized polygons are however returning the expected result.  154 out of 3131 polygons have NULL values

I have used the Identify tool to check that I do have non-null values in the underlying DEM for a bunch of these.

[image: Screenshot of Identify tool output showing DEM value and NULL from Zonal Statistics]

The problem appears to be the FID is not being created for the Zonal Statistics table for some polygons.  I have checked a couple of other small polygons and the values obtained from Zonal Statistics appear correct.  What should I be looking for/testing? How can I correct this?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop v10.6 with Advanced License.

Comment: Have you tried [resampling](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/resample.htm) the DEM to a higher resolution?

Comment: Thank you - that has fixed the problem (if you post an answer I will accept it).  Can you please explain why this would fix things?

Comment: SIMILAR QUESTION: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261429/some-zones-disappear-when-running-zonal-statistics-as-table-in-arcgis/261457#261457

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [resampling](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/resample.htm) the raster to a finer resolution. Not sure why this works but accourding to the [help section for version 10.3](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) (not present in 10.6):

> If the zone input is a feature dataset with relatively small features,
>   keep in mind that the resolution of the information needs to be
>   appropriate relative to the resolution of the value raster. If the
>   areas of single features are similar to or smaller than the area of
>   single cells in the value raster, in the feature-to-raster conversion
>   some of these zones may not be represented.

Comment: I had the same problem. Especially features that were very thin had null values. So I think when they do not cross the centroid of the raster cell, you get NULLS.